# Yii2 custom logger for exceptions

Tags: php, logging, error-handling, yii2

As I understand, in Yii2 all uncaught exceptions logged with `LEVEL_ERROR` of `yii\log\Logger` if there config `log` component of `app`.

How I can set other custom *level* for log exception of my own class `MyException` for example, `LEVEL_WARNING` ? Other words I want to throw an exception, with custom log *level*.

How I can set custom *category* log exception of my own class `MyException` ?

Comment: Have you tried anything?